# Optimize a bunch of nested SELECTs in a MS ACCESS query

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

This is a MS Access query that runs very slow. The `Results` table is the main table and the `P`, `B`, `S` and `C` tables are child tables. The column combination `Index` and `ResultID` is unique in all of these tables. So for instance, there can only be one row in the table `C` where `Index` is "1" and `ResultID` is 2. I'm not using JOIN because MS Access only support inner joins and what I'd need is an outer join because I want to show all records in the table `Results` even if there is no corresponding record in any other table.

```
SELECT 
    [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL],
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "0") as P0,
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "1") as P1,
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "2") as P2,
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "3") as P3,
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "4") as P4,
    (SELECT P.P FROM P WHERE P.ResultID = Results.Id AND P.Index = "5") as P5,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "0") as B0,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "1") as B1,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "2") as B2,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "3") as B3,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "4") as B4,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "5") as B5,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "6") as B6,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "7") as B7,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "8") as B8,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "9") as B9,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "10") as B10,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "11") as B11,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "12") as B12,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "13") as B13,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "14") as B14,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "15") as B15,
    (SELECT B.B FROM B WHERE B.ResultID = Results.Id AND B.Index = "16") as B16,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "1") as S1,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "2") as S2,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "3") as S3,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "4") as S4,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "5") as S5,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "6") as S6,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "7") as S7,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "8") as S8,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "9") as S9,
    (SELECT S.S FROM S WHERE S.ResultID = Results.Id AND S.Index = "10") as S10,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "0") as C0,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "1") as C1,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "2") as C2,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "3") as C3,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "4") as C4,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "5") as C5,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "6") as C6,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "7") as C7,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "8") as C8,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "9") as C9,
    (SELECT C.C FROM C WHERE C.ResultID = Results.Id AND C.Index = "10") as C10
FROM 
    Results
```

Comment: What's lead you to believe Access doesn't support outer joins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure where you got the following:

> *I'm not using JOIN because MS Access only support inner joins and what I'd need is an outer join*

MS Access supports [`OUTER JOIN` syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx).

You can replace your correlated subqueries with a `LEFT JOIN` between each table.  Your code will be similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL],
    max(IIF(P.Index = "0", P.P, null)) as P0,
    max(IIF(P.Index = "1", P.P, null)) as P1,
    max(IIF(P.Index = "2", P.P, null)) as P2,
    max(IIF(P.Index = "3", P.P, null)) as P3,
    max(IIF(P.Index = "4", P.P, null)) as P4,
    max(IIF(P.Index = "5", P.P, null)) as P5,
    max(IIF(B.Index = "0", B.B, null)) as B0,
    max(IIF(B.Index = "1", B.B, null)) as B1,
    max(IIF(B.Index = "8", B.B, null)) as B8,
    max(IIF(S.Index = "2", S.S, null)) as S2,
    max(IIF(C.Index = "1", C.C, null)) as C1
FROM Results
LEFT JOIN P
    on P.ResultID = Results.Id
LEFT JOIN B
    on B.ResultID = Results.Id
LEFT JOIN S
    on S.ResultID = Results.Id
LEFT JOIN C
    on C.ResultID = Results.Id
GROUP BY [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL]
```

You should also be able to *pivot* the data using the `TRANSFORM` function, the code will be similar to this:

```
TRANSFORM Max(Src.Value)
select 
    [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL]
from results as R
left join
(
    select ResultID, P as Value, "P"&Index as col
    from p
    union all
    select ResultID, B as Value, "B"&Index as col
    from B
    union all
    select ResultID, C as Value, "C"&Index as col
    from C
    union all
    select ResultID, S as Value, "S"&Index as col
    from S
) as Src
    on R.id = Src.ResultID
GROUP BY [Results].[Id], [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],[Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName], [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL]
PIVOT Src.col
```

Comment: Why the group by? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @ypercube There is an aggregate function

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. If you put the `Index = '0'` conditions at the `ON` clauses, you wouldn't need the GROUP BY nor the aggregates, right?.

Comment: @ypercube the problem is that they have a different index value for each column, then want to return.

Comment: Ah ok, I now see the light. You want to avoid the 40+ outer joins and do just 4. OK.

Comment: @ypercube yes, you can do the 40+ joins but this would be easier

Comment: @Brad I did not copy your answer if that is what you are getting at

Comment: @Brad: bluefeet has answered more than 300 questions tagged with `[pivot]` and [is the Top-1 answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/topusers) in this type of questions.

Comment: @JuanLuisSoldi you need to concatenate the letter `P` and the `Index` from that table. This will uniquely identify each row to be transform into a column.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will run faster if you make the joins explicit.  Here is the template:

```
SELECT 
    [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL],
    max(iif(p.index = "0", p.p, "")) as p0,
    . . .
FROM results left outer join
     p
     on results.id = p.resultid left outer join
     . . .
group by [Results].[Id],
    [Results].[Name],
    [Results].[OfferPrice],
    [Results].[RegPrice],
    [Results].[ImageFileName],
    [Results].[Image],
    [Results].[URL]
```

The idea is to use `left outer join` to bring in the tables and join them on the correct conditions and use aggregation to shrink them back to one row per result.  The logic in the `SELECT` chooses the values according to the logic you have set up.

Answer (score 1):

This should run pretty quickly. It looks like you are trying to do a pivot on the join between one table and the union of several tables. The `unionized` table below replaces all your joins. And the fact that this is pivoted replaces the need to do any correlated sub queries.

```
TRANSFORM Max(unionized.DataColumn) AS MaxOfDataColumn
SELECT Results.ResName, Results.OfferPrice, Results.RegPrice, Results.Image, Results.URL
FROM (
    Select B.ID, B.B as DataColumn, "B"&B.B as tableName from B
    union all select C.ID, C.C, "C"&C.C from C
    union all select P.ID, P.P, "P"&P.P from P
    union all select S.ID, S.S, "S"&S.S from S)  AS unionized 
RIGHT JOIN Results ON unionized.ID = Results.ID
GROUP BY Results.ResName, Results.OfferPrice, Results.RegPrice, Results.Image, Results.URL
PIVOT unionized.tableName;
```

You'll need to clean it up a bit because i assume you were using example columns but hopefully you get the idea.